# Symfony4 : create custom ROLES

Tags: php, symfony, permissions, symfony4, roles

I know there is a way to create and manage custom roles on a symfony app, but I don't find any documentation or tutorial, so I tried to do it alone and I didn't succeed. Here is what I did:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_TEST:
    ROLE_USER: ROLE_TEST
    ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
```

`ROLE_TEST` should be a lower role than `ROLE_USER` and my Users who are granted `ROLE_TEST` can access to method protected by `@IsGranted("ROLE_USER")` (and they souldn't)

So my question is what's missing?

Comment: I think you imagine it the wrong way.

your setting should mean: 
ROLE_USER will be able to access method protected by @IsGranted("ROLE_TEST")


to be able to do what you wanted
perhaps you can switch the role

ROLE_USER:
ROLE_TEST: ROLE_USER
ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_TEST

Comment: remove the first line in your role_hierarchy

Comment: What you want is, that a user with `ROLE_TEST` can access the content that is restricted with `@IsGranted("ROLE_USER")`?  If so you should reverse the hierarchy so that `ROLE_TEST: ROLE_USER`, because right now if you grant permission to `@IsGranted("ROLE_TEST")` a all your roles will have access through the hierarchy, because ROLE TEST < ROLE_USER < ROLE_ADMIN.

Comment: Yes of course, but ROLE_TEST shouldn't access method protected by @IsGranted("ROLE_USER")

Comment: Oh, so you mean they do have access, but they shouldn't. I get it. Do you have the `debug-pack` installed and have the toolbar on the bottom of the page? If so, click on the icon for security (it should show the logged in user's name). On the security tab, please check which roles the user has and which voter granted permission.

Comment: Database is saying I have ["ROLE_LESSEE"], but debug toolbar is saying :
`Roles 
[▼
  "ROLE_LESSEE"
  "ROLE_USER"
]
Inherited Roles 
[▼
  "ROLE_LESSEE"
]` so now I understand what's the problem, thanks ! I'll try to find where is he from

Comment: Sure thing. Let us know if we can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading comments, I think if you followed Symfony documentation for your login system, you should have this :

```
$roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
```

in your getRoles method, just replace 'ROLE_USER' by '' and try again to use your methods with @IsGranted("ROLE_USER")